# Better approach for login implementation without internet connection and matching password from local db

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I am integrating log in in my app. There is a requirement for log in without internet connection. Means first time when user gets login there will be a web service call for log in authentication but next time the web service call should not be needed it should authenticate from local db of device. First time on log in response I am saving user credentials in local db (means device db using sqlite) and for rest of the attempts I am matching credentials from local db for authentication. For authentication, password is a plan text in local db and I am matching plan passwords. It this good idea/approach to match password as a plan text or I am supposed to be using any encryption? If encryption is required so why is it needed so. I mean when db file is stored internally no one can fetch password.So why encryption is needed?

Comment: when some one change password on website then it will never work.

Comment: If consider that there is never a case of changing password from server or website then??

Comment: It will work on same device in which you have logged in. and no need to encrypt your data.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever store passwords in plain text anywhere. Event when it's local and nobody has access to it.
The better approach is storing it using a hashing algorithm along with salt so the if password is leaked somewhere, no harm should come of it.
You can then hash the input password with the same algorithm and verify it with one you have previously stored.

Here are some links to get you started on hashing:

1. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm
2. http://howtodoinjava.com/security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/